# Spring MVC thymeleaf cannot resolve object attribute and fields

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've just started to discover Spring MVC and got stuck with this simple project. In the template index1.html a player object (th:object="${player}") and field values (th:field="*{playerId}"), (th:field="*{playerName}") can't be resolved. The same situation in template index2.html with (${player.playerId}) and (${player.playerName}). Could you suggest what may be the reason for that?

**PlayerController.java**

```
@Controller
public class PlayerController {

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("player", new Player());
    return "create";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute Player player, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("player", player);

    String info = String.format("Player Submission: playerId = %d, playerName = %s",
            player.getPlayerId(), player.getPlayerName());
    log.info(info);
    return "view";
}
```

}

**The Model**

```
public class Player{

private int playerId;
private String playerName;

.... getters and setters
}
```

**The Views**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" >
    <title>Form Submission</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Player</h1>
    <form action = "#" th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${player}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{playerId}" /></p>
        <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{playerName}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Add" /></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Player info</title>
</head>
<body>

<p th:text="'ID: ' + ${player.playerId}" />
<p th:text="'Name: ' + ${player.playerName}" />

</body>
</html>
```

**Project Structure**
[Click to see the Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc04s.jpg)

Comment: where do you have located yours html files? should be ito /resources/templates

Comment: @cralfaro Yes, the html files are located in /resources/templates. I have attached the Project structure screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `return "redirect:` to transfer a http request to your view page.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute Player player, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("player", player);

        String info = String.format("Player Submission: playerId = %d, playerName = %s",
                player.getPlayerId(), player.getPlayerName());
        log.info(info);
        return "redirect:view";
       // OR return "redirect:/view";
    }
```

Another approach which I recommend is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("player")) {

    log.info(info);
    return "redirect:/view";
}
```